# Proving $n^4 - n$ is not divisible by 4 for an infinite number of $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need a little bit of help with this question:

Show that there are an infinite number of positive integers n such that $n^4 - n$ is not divisible by 4.

Obviously, this is true for all $n$ except for *multiples of* 4.

I assume that I'm supposed the problem either by contradiction or induction - If I perform induction, I reach the following steps:

$$(n+1)^4 - (n+1) = n^4 + 4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n + 1 - (n+1) = 4k $$

Which gives us a polynomial that is not divisible by 4 into an integer except when $n = 4$. Is this enough to prove it? Or is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: all n except multiples of 4

Comment: Note, this is not true for any *multiple* of $4$, e.g. $8^4 - 8 = 4088$. Thus a proof by induction isn't going to work: certainly the $n = 7$ case cannot imply the $n = 8$ case!

Comment: Yeah, sorry! Forgot to write multiples of 4 - my bad. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: The title doesn't agree with the question. Are you trying to find all $n$ with $4|n^4 - n$ or show that there exist infinitely many such $n$?

Comment: The latter - the point is to show that there exist an infinite number of n's that are not divisible by 4 - sorry if that was confusing!

Comment: @Barney $5^4-5=620$, a multiple of four. $9^4-9=6552$, another multiple of four. It turns out that if $n$ is one of $1,5,9,13,\dots,4k+1,\dots$, then it's a multiple of four.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$n^4-n=n(n^3-1)=n(n-1)(n^2+n+1)$$

Now, $n^2+n+1=2\cdot\dfrac{n(n+1)}2+1$ is odd

So, $4|(n^4-n)\iff4|n(n-1)$

Comment: If $4|n(n-1)$ then we can write that $4|n \ or \ 4|(n-1)$ because one is even and the other is odd. If so, then we can deduce that $n^4-n$ is divisible by 4 for n=4k or n=4k+1 for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think this solution covers it - especially the example of n=5 listed above - So n=9, 13, 17, etc. would all be legitimate solutions as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Galc127, In fact, $(n,n-1)=1$

Answer (score 5):

For all positive integers $k$, $$(4k-2)^4-(4k-2)=4(64k^4-128k^3+96k^2-33k+4)+2$$
is not divisible by $4$.

Comment: You showed that $n^4-n$ is not divisible by 4 for all even numbers that are not divisible by 4. What about n=3 for example?

Comment: @Galc127 It seems the question was worded quite confusingly; the task was to show that it's true for infinitely many integers, not to find all true cases.

Comment: @Galc127: As Eul Can comments, my understanding is that the OP asks us to prove that there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $n^4-n$ is not divisible by $4$.

Comment: @Galc127: I'm sorry for the confusion - I explained in a less than exemplary manner, so I apologize - mathlove and Eul Can are correct

Answer (score 2):

You can check that $2^4-2$ is not divisible by $4$. Next, note that if $n^4-n$ is not divisible by $4$, then
$$
(n+4)^4-(n+4)=(4A - 4) + n^4-n
$$
is also not divisible by $4$. ($A$ is an integer that can be found by the Binomial Theorem.)

Answer (score 0):

Working in $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ we find $\bar{2}^{4}-\bar{2}=\bar{2}$
showing that $4\nmid\left(4m+2\right)^{4}-\left(4m+2\right)$ for
each integer $m$.

Answer (score 0):

$n^4 - n$ is divisible by $4$ for $n \equiv 0$ or $n \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

$n^4 - n$ leaves remainder $2$ when divided by $4$ for $n \equiv 2$ or $n \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.